# How can I find the nearest point of intrest to my current location with the Windows Phone Map control?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I need to find out nearest location (in this case doctor's offices) from user current location using using Map control on windows phone 8.1.

I have my locations available in and XML file (latitude, longitude).

Is there a function that can return to me the distance to all of the points in my XML file?

Is there a way I can run that function asynchronously or in the background?

Is there a way I can animate the pin on the map (e.g., make it appear to jump)?

Comment: You start with what everybody else does: [You look in the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh465120.aspx)

Comment: If you can make this question more generic, as in for seeking the route for the nearest location, and isolate the the two questions in the bottom, it would be ideal for you to get an clear answer individually.

Comment: Hi hirosht,
I want to know how can i make distance calculating funcationality in background so page would not be remain in loading screen more time.
And animation on image to indicate user that this is the nearest Location

Comment: I've distilled the question down to it's main points - the context (the first two sentences) and the question(s) (the last three sentences). There really are three questions here, and this should have been broken up into three different questions. However, since it has been answered and the answer has been accepted, I don't see a point to breaking it up now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To calculate the distance, I always use following Extension method on the `BasicGeoposition` class.
To do this in the background, use a `Task.Run(() => )`.

```
public static double GetDistanceTo(this BasicGeoposition from, double toLatitude, double toLongitude)
{
    if (double.IsNaN(from.Latitude) || double.IsNaN(from.Longitude))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("On of the given Latitude or Longitudes is not correct");
    }
    else
    {
        double latitude = from.Latitude * 0.0174532925199433;
        double longitude = from.Longitude * 0.0174532925199433;
        double num = toLatitude * 0.0174532925199433;
        double longitude1 = toLongitude * 0.0174532925199433;
        double num1 = longitude1 - longitude;
        double num2 = num - latitude;
        double num3 = Math.Pow(Math.Sin(num2 / 2), 2) + Math.Cos(latitude) * Math.Cos(num) * Math.Pow(Math.Sin(num1 / 2), 2);
        double num4 = 2 * Math.Atan2(Math.Sqrt(num3), Math.Sqrt(1 - num3));
        double num5 = 6376500 * num4;

        return num5;
    }            
}
```

Comment: Hi Depechie,
Thanks for your ans. Can you please give me idea how can i Do "Task.Run(() => )",
I am new in windows phone app development. If you give me sample code, that would be more helpful to me

Comment: Well there is a good series on Async programming oon MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx and some details on Task.Run http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/10/24/10229468.aspx